# why ansible doesn't recognize the vcenter windows machines?

Tags: virtualization, configuration, ansible, deployment, vmware-vcenter

I'm pretty new with Ansible so I might configured things wrong 
[I have a Docker container running Ansible service in it
I have an Ansible repository that include the Ansible files (this is a .Git repository]

My will was to **automatically revert each lab in vCenter server to a specific snapshot** 
So, I (with the help of [ansible-roles-explained-with-examples guide](https://www.learnitguide.net/2018/02/ansible-roles-explained-with-examples.html)):

- Created a role with `ansible-galaxy init` command name `vcenter` (see directory tree below)
- Created some vcenter tasks files inside `tasks` folder (see directory tree below). Here is an example of `poweroff.yml` task file:

```yaml
- name: Set the state of a virtual machine to poweroff
  community.vmware.vmware_guest_powerstate:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    folder: "/{{ datacenter_name }}/{{ folder }}"
    # name: "{{ guest_name }}"
    name: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    validate_certs: no
    state: powered-off
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: deploy
```

- Supplied vCenter credentials in `vcenter\vars\main.yml` file, like this:

```yaml
# vars file for vcenter
vcenter_hostname: vcenter.foo.com
vcenter_username: hiddai@foo.com
vcenter_password: f#0$o#1$0o
datacenter_name: FOO_Fighters
# datastore_name: 
cluster_name: FOO
folder: '/FOO/PRODUCT/DOMAIN.COM/'
```

- Included the tasks in `tasks\main.yml` file with `import-task` key, like this:

```yaml
---
# tasks file for roles/vcenter
- import_tasks: poweroff.yml
# - import_tasks: poweron.yml
# - import_tasks: revert.yml
# - import_tasks: shutdown.yml
```

- Created a `all.yml` inside group_vars folder in inventories library (i don't know if its a professional way to do like that) that include all winrm details like this:

```yaml
---
#WinRM Protocol Details
ansible_user: DOMAIN\user
ansible_password: f#0$o#1$0o
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_winrm_scheme: http
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 60
ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec: 58
```

- Created a `revert_lab.yml` playbook that include the role, like this

```yaml
---
- name: revert an onpremis lab
  hosts: all
  roles:
  - vcenter
```

My `ansible.cfg` is like this:

```yaml
[defaults]
inventory = /ansible/inventories
roles_path = ./roles:..~/ansible/roles
```

I executed the playbook to revert all the machines in the lab:

```sh
ansible-playbook playbooks/revert_vcenter_lab.yml -i inventories/test/onpremis/domain.com/lab_r.yml
```

The error I got was:

```sh
TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Error when collecting winrm facts: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At line:15 char:17  + ...
$ansibleFacts.ansible_win_rm_certificate_expires = $_.Not ...  +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          :  
InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull      at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 15  at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line  
13
ok: [vm1.domain.com]
ok: [vm2.domain.com]
ok: [vm3.domain.com]
ok: [vm4.domain.com]
ok: [vm5.domain.com]
ok: [vm6.domain.com]
ok: [vm7.domain.com]
ok: [vm8.domain.com]

TASK [vcenter : Set the state of a virtual machine to poweroff] ***********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [vm1.domain.com -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to set power state for non-existing virtual machine : 'VM1'"}
fatal: [vm2.domain.com -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to set power state for non-existing virtual machine : 'VM2'"}
fatal: [vm3.domain.com -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to set power state for non-existing virtual machine : 'VM3'"}
fatal: [vm4.domain.com -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to set power state for non-existing virtual machine : 'VM4'"}
fatal: [vm5.domain.com -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to set power state for non-existing virtual machine : 'VM5'"}
fatal: [vm6.domain.com -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to set power state for non-existing virtual machine : 'VM6'"}
fatal: [vm7.domain.com -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to set power state for non-existing virtual machine : 'VM7'"}
fatal: [vm8.domain.com -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to set power state for non-existing virtual machine : 'VM8'"}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
vm1.domain.com   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
vm2.domain.com   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
vm3.domain.com   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
vm4.domain.com   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
vm5.domain.com   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
vm6.domain.com   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
vm7.domain.com   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
vm8.domain.com   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

a) **How do I get rid of the `Error when collecting winrm facts` error?** (It is look like that the playbook is not recognize the `all.yml` file with the win, but why?) 
b) **How do I fix the error "Unable to set power state for non-existing virtual machine..."**? (We can see that the playbook access to the machines by fqdns mentioned in the lab_r.yml file (from the inventories library) but the error relates to the machine name as displayed in the vCenter platform...)

*My repository:*

```sh
C:.
├───ansible
│   │   ansible.cfg
│   ├───inventories
│   │   └───test
│   │       ├───cloud
│   │       └───onpremis
│   │           └───domain.com
│   │               │   lab_j.yml
│   │               │   lab_r.yml
│   │               └───group_vars
│   │                       all.yml
│   ├───playbooks
│   │       revert_lab.yml
│   └───roles
│       └───vcenter
│           ├───tasks
│           │       main.yml
│           │       poweroff.yml
│           │       poweron.yml
│           │       revert.yml
│           │       shutdown.yml
│           └───vars
│                   main.yml
```

*My inventory* `lab_r.yml` - this is a partial schema

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    root:
      children:
        center:
          children:
            appservers:
              hosts:
                vm1.domain.com:
            qservers:
              hosts:
                vm2.domain.com:
            dbservers:
              hosts:
                vm3.domain.com:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very obvious from the documentation, but the string `/vm/` is missing in your folder path.

```yaml
- name: Set the state of a virtual machine to poweroff
  community.vmware.vmware_guest_powerstate:
    folder: "/{{ datacenter_name }}/vm/{{ folder }}"
    name: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
```

I guess it is needed to distinguish between other resources in the datacenter, datastores, hosts, etc.

Comment: First, I added ```--verbos``` to the playbook command, it just added this line: ```Using /ansible/ansible.cfg as config file``` to output before the ```PLAY``` lines everything else remain the same. In addition, I performed your suggestion - adding ```/vm/``` string - output and errors remained the same (as in the main post). More over, I don't understand why ```ansible_hostname``` work and ```guest_name``` doesn't...?

Comment: I didn't solve question a but solve question b by setting ```folder: "/{{ datacenter_name }}/"```

Comment: This will not help you if you have more than one VM with the same name in different folders.

Comment: another fact that I found: If I execute poweroff.yml task on my lab - the machine are turned-off successfully. When I execute poweron.yml task on my turned-off lab, I get ```fatal: [srraalabrst1.r10.local]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ntlm: HTTPConnectionPool(host='vm1.domain.com', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fcf6a6b6080>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))", "unreachable": true}```

Comment: Most probably you are trying the next task too fast after turning on the VM. You can configure ansible to retry this, but you should ask a new question about that.

Comment: In addition by your help, I found with ```--verbos``` that the folder is really comes with ```/vm/```: ```"hw_folder": "/FOO/vm/PRODUCT/DOMAIN.COM/```. I set the vars.yml file with this path and the ```folder``` parameters with ```/vm/``` as well. Output is still remain the same. Will open a new question for that. Thanks @Gerald.